# add js file in my custom plugin page only in wordpress not other pages

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Add js file in my custom plugin page only in wordpress not other pages?

I need to make and add js in my custom plugin.

Comment: duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41207/how-do-i-enqueue-styles-scripts-on-certain-wp-admin-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have your plugin running only on a single page called About. So I guess here you need to manually load the js file on that page only and want to take it out of other pages.

Create a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) called page-about.php. At the top put

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Plugin JS page
*/
```

Then copy-paste what's in your header.php to it, then under that add what's in your page.php, then under that call get_footer(). Now it exactly replicates the normal page.

Now go and get rid of the js file that is loading in your normal homepage (header.php) and leave it in place on the page-about.php that you just created. (Alternatively, just add the call to the js file in the page-about.php header area you copied.)

Finally, go and edit page About and change its page template to Plugin JS page.

Maybe that helped you.